# Securing a public rest server on a small network

Tags: linux, security, webserver

I have a rest server app under development (written in Java) that I want to make publically accessible, possibly using docker (just to get some experience of that). As there seems to be no free managed hosting for small java projects available I'm considering using a machine on my home network. I obviously don't want to compromise the security of my network but neither do I want managing the server to become a lifetime's work.

RHEL seems to have a good reputation as a secure and regularly-updated linux distro so I'm quite drawn to CentOS. I see though that Openwall (OWL) is being touted as a good hardened distro. My other option would be to use a FreeBSD jail.

Is one of these, with security fixes being automatically applied, and running within the DMZ of my network going to give me sufficient protection out of the box?

Comment: Public to who ? Every one on the internet or just a small group of peoples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which lets you run Java Servlets in Tomcat. You can get it free for a year: https://aws.amazon.com/free/ .

Otherwise, you should be okay running a server in your DMZ. I'm a fan of OpenBSD.

The main thing is to actually know if you've been compromised. For this you need a second computer to send logs to, else hacker can modify your logs. Also have a good backup/restore process.

So, set up a second computer with the following:

syslogd (rsyslog is good)
HIDS server (OSSEC is good)
NIDS server (snort is good. setup port mirroring on your switch)
ntpd (time server, use OpenNTPD) †

And the appropriate clients on your REST server to communicate with the above.

† If a hacker can change your system time, it's as good as changing your logs